# VFS SFTP upload sending directory structure, not just file

Tags: groovy, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

I am attempting to upload a file to an SFTP site, but the entire directory structure is being recreated on the SFTP site instead of just uploading the file at the root. I am calling sendSftp (see below).

```
public void sendSftp(String filename, IPropertyHelper ph) {
    def local = VFS.getManager().toFileObject(new File("${filename}"))
    def remote = VFS.getManager().resolveFile(buildSftpPath(filename, ph), new FileSystemOptions());
    remote.copyFrom(local, Selectors.SELECT_SELF) 
}

private String buildSftpPath(filename, IPropertyHelper ph) {
    return "sftp://${ph.properties.sftp_Login}:${ph.properties.sftp_Password}@${ph.properties.sftp_Hostname}/${filename}"
}
```

Any help in how to send just the file and place it at the root of the SFTP site would be great, thanks!

Comment: does changing `def local = VFS.getManager().toFileObject(new File("${filename}"))` to `def local = VFS.manager.resolveFile( filename )` help?

Comment: Same result, sends the entire directory structure.

Comment: What is `filename`? I suspect `buildSftpPath(filename, ph)` is building the full directory structure...  Try `buildSftpPath(new File( filename ).name, ph)`

Comment: Thanks tim_yates, that's the answer!

Comment: Added as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `filename`? I suspect `buildSftpPath(filename, ph)` is building the full directory structure... Try `buildSftpPath(new File( filename ).name, ph)`